# Center Image and Text in Heading

Tags: css

I want to create a heading that comprises of an image which is about three lines high, and text  that I want to put to the immediate right of that.  With the whole heading centered.

```
<center><h1><img.../>Text of heading which is a little long</h1></center>
```

The problem arises if the window is narrowed, the heading wraps underneath the image.  I want to somehow put the text in a box that warps, but sits immediately to the right of the img box, the whole lot centered.

So wrapped like

```
    IIII  TTT TTT
    IIII  TT TTT
```

Not like this

```
    IIII  TTT TTT
    IIII
    TT TTT
```

(where the Is are the image, the Ts the text).

I have tried various permutations to no avail.  Floating does not do it.  Maybe this needs a table?

(The H1 need only enclose the text, not the Img.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a div, then position the div center with `flex`

Like so:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: I wonder how widely supported flex is.  E.g. on older mobile phones.

Comment: Interesting thought.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I just kept it simple

```
  <center><table><tr>
  <td><img></td><td>Heading text</td>
  </tr></table></center>
```

Just ancient HTML, using tables what they are meant for.  Should have thought of it earlier rather than getting carried away with box models.